# Converting tensorflow v1 to v2 without compatability.v1

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am in the process of converting this code `predictor.py` located [here](https://github.com/YadiraF/PRNet/blob/master/predictor.py) to tensorflow v2 with Python 3.7.  I want to do this conversion part by part. So from the refence repo, I've been going through [this example](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/a174bf5b1db0e2c1e04697ff5aae5182bd1c60e7/official/vision/image_classification/resnet/resnet_model.py).

For this block:

```
def resBlock(x, num_outputs, kernel_size = 4, stride=1, activation_fn=tf.nn.relu, normalizer_fn=tcl.batch_norm, scope=None):
    assert num_outputs%2==0 #num_outputs must be divided by channel_factor(2 here)
    with tf.variable_scope(scope, 'resBlock'):
        shortcut = x
        if stride != 1 or x.get_shape()[3] != num_outputs:
            shortcut = tcl.conv2d(shortcut, num_outputs, kernel_size=1, stride=stride, 
                        activation_fn=None, normalizer_fn=None, scope='shortcut')
        x = tcl.conv2d(x, num_outputs/2, kernel_size=1, stride=1, padding='SAME')
        x = tcl.conv2d(x, num_outputs/2, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding='SAME')
        x = tcl.conv2d(x, num_outputs, kernel_size=1, stride=1, activation_fn=None, padding='SAME', normalizer_fn=None)

        x += shortcut       
        x = normalizer_fn(x)
        x = activation_fn(x)
    return x
```

Here is what I have

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation, BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, Conv2DTranspose
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.regularizers import l2

def create_sub_model(
                   filters=16,
                   kernel_size=4,
                   stride=(1,1),
                   stage=0,
                   block='1a',
                   activation='relu',
                   normalizer=BatchNormalization()):

  assert (filters % 2 == 0), __file__ + ":filters is not an integer"
  name_base = 'conv' + str(stage) + block + '_branch'
  model = Sequential()
  #initial layer
  model.add(Conv2D(filters / 2, kernel_size=1, stride=(1, 1), padding='same',
                   name=conv_name_base + '2a'))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(name=bn_name_base + '2a'))
  model.add(Activation(activation))
  #add layer
  model.add(Conv2D(filters / 2, kernel_size=kernel_size, stride=stride, padding='same',
                   name=conv_name_base + '2b'))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(name=bn_name_base + '2b'))
  model.add(Activation(activation))
  # add layer
  model.add(Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=1, stride=(1,1), padding='same',
                   name=conv_name_base + '2c',activation=None, normalizer=None))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(name=bn_name_base + '2c'))
  model.add(Activation(activation))
  # add layer
  model.add(Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=1, stride=stride, padding='same',
                   name=conv_name_base + '2d', activation=None, normalizer=None))
  model.add(BatchNormalization(normalizername=bn_name_base + '2d'))
  model.add(Activation(activation))
  return model
```

I want to avoid defining the input tensor until later.  Is this going down the right way?